# Specify the step between major gridlines in kendo dataviz area chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I've created an area chart, illustrating the status of many media players throughout a single day.

I want there to be a major gridline at every hour, and a minor gridline at every half hour.
I cannot see where you can set the "step" of the grid line.

Here's how I'm currently setting it up:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    theme: "blueOpal",
    title: {
        visible:false
    },
    chartArea: {
        height: 800
    },
    legend: {
        position: "bottom"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "area",
        stack: true
    },
    series: [],
    valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: "{0}",
            visible: true
        }
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: [],
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            step:60
        },
        minorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: true,
        },
        majorTicks: {
            visible: false,
            size: 2
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0}"
    },
    seriesColors: [
            '#336699',
            '#EBAD60',
            '#FF0000',
            '#9582BB',
            '#028482'
    ]
});
```

And it looks like this. This shrunken image displays less gridlines that are actually displayed, but this image still indicates that that there are so many lines that they stop serving a purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the same question on the Telerik forums:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/dataviz/chart/specify-the-step-between-major-gridlines-in-a-datetime-series.aspx#2378855

The answer is: you cannot set the gridline step in Kendo UI DataViz.

Hopefully I will have a reason to come back and update this answer in 2013.

---

**Later edit**

Finally, 
In the 2014.1 release of Kendo UI, you can specify the frequency of vertical grid lines. This is done by the configuration properties `categoryAxis.majorGridLines.step` and `categoryAxis.minorGridLines.step`

```
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: [],
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            step: 60
        },
        minorGridLines: {
            visible: true,
            step: 30
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: true,
            step: 60
        },
        majorTicks: {
            visible: false,
            size: 2
        }
    },
```